# Vue.js import problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, import

**I have a problem with the import of Vue and it is the following.**

In the beginning, I have this like below:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import "bootstrap";
import "./assets/stylesB.css";

create(App).use(router).mount("#app");
```

but I want to add two imports:

```
import { ValidationProvider } from "vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full.esm";
import { ValidationObserver } from "vee-validate";
```

These two imports need the instance of Vue, but when I go to add it, it returns an error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is not a constructor
  at eval(vee-validate.full.esm.js?6f19:1032
  at Module../node_modules/vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full.esm.js (chunk-vendors.js:2216)
  at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
  at fc (app.js:151)
  at eval (main.js:16)
  at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1145)
  at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
  at fn (app.js:151)
  at Object.1 (app.js:1170)
  at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
```

**I'm new in Vue, please don't take it the wrong way**

Comment: Please read [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vee-validate) on how to use vee-validate ... hint: the documentation says `import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';` - so, you haven't followed instructions at all

Comment: You can register vee-validate globally in main.js or locally in a component but Bravo is correct you are not importing it as outlined in the documentation.

Comment: I import in local in my file Register.vue but the error persist. and i dont know how to solve  it